# How would I update Windows for versions 2004 and above?

Tags: windows, updates, vmware

I am trying to run VMWare and the website states to disable Hyper-V (which I did), but then at the bottom it said versions 1909 of Windows 10 and earlier cannot run VMWare at all, and I am at version 1909. How do I update my Windows 10 version to be the latest? (and will it corrupt/delete my files?)

Thanks!

Comment: Download the latest windows 10 version (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), run it and select upgrade. Upgrade does not delete user files.

Comment: Thanks! Now on the latest version.